# Accessing arbitrary keys in KVMs from JavaScript policy

Tags: apigee

[`apigee-access`](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/nodejs/using-apigee-access) provides a way for KVMs to be accessed under node.js [via javascript](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/nodejs/accessing-key-value-maps-nodejs):

`var kvm = apigee.getKeyValueMap('kvm_name', 'scope');`

Are there any similar functionalities available from within a [javascript policy](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/javascript-policy)? In my usage scenario I'd like to access arbitrarily defined keys from a known KVM.